# TypeError: Cannot read property "dark" of undefined

Tags: node.js, json, visual-studio-code, fs, theming

Tried recreating Github's [Theme](https://github.com/primer/github-vscode-theme) for vscode. It takes multiple json files to create multiple vscode theme extensions. My file structure is something like this:

```
src
|_ themeColors
|  |__ dark.json
|  |__ dimmed.json
|  |__ light.json
|_ color.js
|_ index.js
|_ theme.js
```

index.js has

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const getTheme = require('./theme');

const darkDefaultTheme = getTheme({
    theme: 'dark',
    name: 'SimpliCT Dark Default',
});

const darkDimmedTheme = getTheme({
    theme: 'dimmed',
    name: 'SimpliCT Dark Dimmed',
});

const lightDefaultTheme = getTheme({
    theme: 'light',
    name: 'SimpliCT Light Default',
});

fs.mkdir('./themes', { recursive: true })
    .then(() => Promise.all([
        fs.writeFile( './themes/dark-default.json', JSON.stringify(darkDefaultTheme, null, 2),),
        fs.writeFile( './themes/dark-dimmed.json', JSON.stringify(darkDimmedTheme, null, 2),),
        fs.writeFile( './themes/light-default.json', JSON.stringify(lightDefaultTheme, null, 2),),
    ]))
    .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

theme.js currently has

```
const chroma = require('chroma-js');
const { getColors } = require('./colors');

const hex = color => {
    return chroma(color).hex();
};

const getTheme = ({ theme, name }) => {
    const color = getColors(theme);

    return {
        name: name,
        colors: {
            foreground: hex(color.bg.dark),
        },
        semanticHighlighting: true,
        semanticTokenColors: {},
        tokenColors: [],
    };
};

module.exports = getTheme;
```

colors.js has

```
const darkColors = require('./themeColors/dark.json');
const dimmedColors = require('./themeColors/dimmed.json');
const lightColors = require('./themeColors/light.json');

function getColors(theme) {
    if (theme === 'dark') {
        return darkColors;
    } else if (theme === 'dimmed') {
        return dimmedColors;
    } else if (theme === 'light') {
        return lightColors;
    }
}

module.exports = { getColors };
```

and lastly, for this example, my dark.json has

```
{
    "bg": {
        "dark": "#12181e",
        "darker": "#0f1318",
        "darkest": "#0c0e12"
    }
}
```

Running the code gives an error and I'm not sure I did wrong. The error is as follows

```
/home/head/documents/GitForks/simplict-vscode/src/theme.js:17
                    foreground: hex(color.bg.dark),
                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'dark' of undefined
    at getTheme (/home/head/documents/GitForks/simplict-vscode/src/theme.js:17:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/head/documents/GitForks/simplict-vscode/src/index.js:9:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain](internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: Please do not add code as images, instead embed it into your question using code blocks. That way it can be copied and also read directly. Also please clarify "gives an error". Please provide the error output or at least the error message.

Comment: Also please clarify if the file is called dark.json or dark.js. If it is dark.js then you need to export the object to require it elsewhere `module.exports = {"bg": {…}}` if it is dark.json then I think you have to change your require statement in the color.js (or colors.js) to `require("./themeColors/dark.json")

Comment: Right, sry about that. That was when I was trying a bunch of things to try and fix the code.. Anyways, it still gives the same error

Comment: Please search this site for *typeerror cannot read property of undefined*. Very similar questions have been asked literally dozens (if not hundreds) of times here before. At least one of them should provide enough information to use to help you solve the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide a minimal working example, that can reproduce the error, next time.
I removed everything that references dimmed.json and light.json since you did not provide those files to us.

index.js

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const getTheme = require('./theme');

const darkDefaultTheme = getTheme({
    theme: 'dark',
    name: 'SimpliCT Dark Default',
});

fs.mkdir('./themes', { recursive: true })
    .then(() => Promise.all([
        fs.writeFile( './themes/dark-default.json', JSON.stringify(darkDefaultTheme, null, 2),),
    ]))
    .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

color.js

```js
const darkColors = require('./themeColors/dark.json');

function getColors(theme) {
    if (theme === 'dark') {
        return darkColors;
    }
}

module.exports = { getColors };
```

theme.js stays the same.

This runs without errors and does generate ./themes/dark-default.json.
The error must originate from either dimmed.json or light.json (maybe both).
The error throws because you want to access `color.bg.dark` (just like the error message says) for that to be possible dimmed.json and light.json must both have a `dark` key under `bg`. I suspect that instead they look like this:

```json
{
  "bg": {
    "light": "#123456",
    …
}
```

If that is the case, you must either change the key name in the dimmed.json and the light.json file to `dark` or you need to change the way that the `getTheme` function accesses it. A really dirty fix might be `hex(color.bg[theme])`. But this might cause problems later on if you ever want to access anything besides `color.bg.dark`, `color.bg.dimmed` and `color.bg.light`. A better approach would be to use the same schema for all your json files.